# Search. Get all values of a Managed Property

Tags: search, sharepoint-enterprise, enterprise-search

I want to build a filer (search) user interface for search results page. Thus a have a few Managed Properties I want users to search by. For example, I have a department property (sting) and I want to have a drop down with all department names. How can I get these values to display in my UI using C# code?

Answer (score 2):

You could probably do this without C#. The Refinements Web Part will display the Managed Properties in results, and you can use an XSLT transformation against this to show the properties in a dropdown.

Comment: Thanks, for the reply, I want to know about C# way cause in the filter web part there will be other controls like text boxes for querying other managed properties like keyword itself and so on. Also there should be a date range selection. Something like advanced search but designed for specific options only.